# Windows 10 execucte shutdown/log off script that requieres admin rights

Tags: windows-10, script, shutdown, administrator

I looked up [microsoft page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn789190(v=ws.11).aspx) for creating turn off and log off scripts,

but they won't trigger, I guess it's because they requiere admin rights. How can I get them fired?

thank you.

Comment: Shutdown scripts run as the System account. Logoff scripts run as the account that is logging off.

Comment: so if the user that logs off is a aministrator... it should work.